# Is there a performance difference between $i++ and ++$i in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I have code like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    // code
}
```

versus code like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    // code
}
```

Could there be any performance difference? I'm asking because, unlike in C, I can't just inspect the compiled file since you don't compile PHP, so how do I even know?

Comment: _Could there be any performance difference?_ Barely any. However, they do have a difference in their usage sometimes.

Comment: If there is any difference, it must be negligible and unless we're talking billions of iterations, not significant enough to worry about.

Comment: Yes, the usage is different. But, however, if you build something with PHP, this doesn't really matter :D Meanwhile PHP has become faster, but not so fast that it would make a difference.